# How to NOT use full controller path in Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

In Laravel web routes I use the full path to a controller like so:

```
'App\Http\Controllers\frontend\EmailController@index'
```

This gets a little long and redundant.  How can I use a path like so:

```
'EmailController@index'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how routes are declared in Laravel any more. You should be doing something like this in modern versions:

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\frontend\EmailController;

Route::get("/email", [EmailController::class, "index"]);
```

IIRC, for older versions the `App\Http\Controllers` was always assumed (or set as a property in the route service provider) and you could just use `"frontend\EmailController@index"`, or wrap it in a route group to remove the "frontend" prefix:

```php
<?php

Route::namespace("frontend")->group(function () {
    Route::get("/email", "EmailController@index");
});
```